# Update an assets file (C#/UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp

I've got a csv file stored in my solutions's assets folder. Every now and then a copy of the csv is updated on a shared drive. Is there a way to copy this file and replace the version in the assets folder automatically. (I'd just reference the shared file rather than an internal one but occasionally the network plays up. I guess I could just have it copy to a location locally but I'd rather do it this way if possible)

I've added something to copy the file over on app launch but don't have permissions. I've guessing that assets are read only during runtime? Is there a way around this?

This is the line of code that triggers the error. `File.Copy(sharedPath, assetPath, true);`

> Error: Access to the path 'C:\Users...AppX\Assets\file.csv' is
> denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Update an assets file (C#/UWP)

During checking the path, and it looks a apps installation folder, unfortunately, the installation folder is **read-only**, we can't write data into. we suggest you use app' [local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/fileio-learning-track) that with full permission.

For your scenario, you could copy the csv file where in the assets folder to app's local folder when app fist launch. when you want to update csv file you just need to replace local folder's csv with shared drive.

For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).